# Список через toggleClass

Tags: html, jquery, css

[image: Скрин списка]
При нажатии на один из пунктов списка через `toggleClass` добавляю `overflow: visible`, и соответственно появляется список. Но проблема, как видно по скрину, в том что можно открыть все списки. Как реализовать выпадение другого списка и скрытие первого.

Пример строчки кода, которая открывает список:

```
$(".works").click(function() {
    $(".works .sub_list").toggleClass("visible");
});
```

Добавление к уже имеющемуся.
Тот код, который я выложил как решение работает, но с новой проблемой.
Список теперь в принципе не закрывается, т.е. при нажатии на любой другой элемент списка предыдущий скрывается, но щелкнув на любую другую область страницы список не закроется. Новая проблема, соответственно нужно новое решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".works").click(function(){
    $(".works .sub_list").removeClass("visible");
    $(this).find(".sub_list").addClass("visible");
 });
```

Comment: Заменил свой код данным. Теперь список, который открыт один раз, больше не закрывается.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так я сделал у себя на сайте. Доволен как слон

```
$('#nav li').hover(function() { 
        $(this).children('ul').show();
    }, function() { 
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
    }
 );
```

Comment: Здесь по ховеру, немножко по другому реализовывается.  
То-есть функцию которая у вас вторая используется всегда, кроме тех случаев, когда запускается функция выше `hover()`.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [xFloooo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15465/xfloooo) за ответ, подтолкнул к нужной мысли.

Вот рабочий код:

`$(".works").click(function(){
    $(".sub_list").removeClass("visible");
    $(".works .sub_list").toggleClass("visible");
 });`